# Copy a file from old revision and keep both of them (old / new revision)

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

I'm using svn, and I have the following situation.

In #1 (rev.1), I commit a file as `/trunk/moduleA/file1`.

Next time, I move the file to `/trunk/moduleB/file2` and modify it, after all I commit it again. It's #2 now.

Later, I want to keep both of them, the old one stores in `/trunk/moduleA/`, but the new one in `/trunk/moduleB` won't be affected. And when I commit again, both of them exist with their own history (`file2` has the history from #1 to #2, and `file1` has only the history #1)

If I revert `file2` to #1, the `file2` will lost and nothing left in `/trunk/moduleB`.

If I update the `/trunk/moduleA` to #1, both of files are exist, but there will be a lot of mass in `/moduleA` since I made a lot of modification between #1 and #2.

Is there any way to solve the situation?

PS. My svn client is TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you're saying.  Can you edit your post and include the specific sequence of Subversion commands/operations that you're doing?  Preferably using the command-line `svn` client, so that the problem is easy to reproduce for others.

If you're simply trying to get an old copy of a file (even if that file no longer exists), you can use a command like:

```
svn copy ${repo}/trunk/moduleA/file1@${rev} ${repo}/trunk/moduleB/file1
```

where `${repo}` is the URL of your repository and `${rev}` is the version of the file that you want.  This will resurrect the old version of that file, including the history up to revision `${rev}`.

Comment: Thanks, almost near, but I want is like `svn copy ${repo}/trunk/moduleA/file1@${rev} ${repo}/trunk/moduleA/file1`. (I want it stay in same position) I'm going to try it now.